# Spring Hosting Combination

Tags: spring, hibernate, tomcat, hosting

I have a Spring + Hibernate + MySQL running on Tomcat 7.

While this may be a silly question I was wondering if anyone recommends a good shared hosting site that will accommodate the above combination.

Reason I'm after shared is that I want it as a basic testing ground and experimentation not full blown operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) allows you to use any combination you'd like on windows or linux. IAAS is great for flexibility and Amazon pricing is attractive.

We've been using it on one of our projects with great success.

For durability you need to attach an EBS volume or replicate your db to S3.

Comment: Thanks Vlad. I'm new to EC2, so for me its bit confusing. Not sure whether i just need EC2 or RDP as well for the mysql bit.

Comment: I think you are referring to RDS, but you don't really need for medium size apps. Just use EBS for durability and you can install mysql on one EC2 instance and your app server on other instance.